# multiple values to a #define constant using or operator

Tags: c++

```
#define DEFAULT_IPV4_PING_TYPES (PINGTYPE_ICMP_PING|PINGTYPE_TCP|PINGTYPE_TCP_USE_ACK|PINGTYPE_TCP_USE_SYN|PINGTYPE_ICMP_TS)
```

What does above syntax actually do?
below are the values for the constants.

```
#define PINGTYPE_ICMP_PING 2
#define PINGTYPE_TCP  16
#define PINGTYPE_TCP_USE_SYN 64
#define PINGTYPE_ICMP_TS 8
```

is it creating a array?

Comment: No, it is defining `(PINGTYPE_ICMP_PING|PINGTYPE_TCP|PINGTYPE_TCP_USE_ACK|PINGTYPE_TCP_USE_SYN|PINGTYPE_ICMP_TS)`. These are the values for constants: `2`, `16`, `64` and `8`.

Comment: it actually creates constant values and not arrays.  PINGTYPE_ICMP_PING|PINGTYPE_TCP|PINGTYPE_TCP_USE_ACK|PINGTYPE_TCP_USE_SYN|PINGTYPE_ICMP_TS this assigns the const value and does the bitwise operator functionality.

Comment: Look up **Bitmasks** on your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro defines a mask for all ping types.

It is bitwise operation

Same as

```
#define PINGTYPE_ICMP_PING 0x2
#define PINGTYPE_TCP  0x10
#define PINGTYPE_TCP_USE_SYN 0x40
#define PINGTYPE_ICMP_TS 0x8
```

When you do bitwise OR you get

```
0x2 | 0x10 | 0x8 | 0x40 = 0x5A
```

it is more clear in binary format (using 8 bits for simplify)

```
00000010 (2)
01000000 (64)
00001000 (8)
00010000 (16)
=============
01011010  (5A)
```